# Ruby - using IRB to test how a new gem is working

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb

I just downloaded the wrapper gem to connect to linkedin with Rby by doing

```
gem install linkedin
```

The origin of this gem is here: https://github.com/genadinik/linkedin

Now I am learning IRB to try to test it.

The purpose of this gem is to be the Ruby wrapper for handling LinkedIn connections.  But I am not sure how to test that it is working.  How would I go about invoking it and testing that my connection keys work to connect, and then running commands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically take the example code you're trying to test, and input into IRB one line at a time.  For example, if I wanted to test the sample code from https://github.com/genadinik/linkedin:

```
$ irb
1.9.2p290 :001 > require 'rubygems'
 => false 
1.9.2p290 :002 > require 'linkedin'
 => true 
1.9.2p290 :003 > client = LinkedIn::Client.new('your_consumer_key', 'your_consumer_secret')
 => #<LinkedIn::Client:0x007fd48b09fdc8 @consumer_token="your_consumer_key",@consumer_secret="your_consumer_secret", @consumer_options={}>
```

And so on.  The line after your input starting with => represents the return value of your input.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Start with opening a command prompt and typing:

```
> irb
irb> require 'linkedin'
irb> #code from the linkedin gem readme
```